# $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}||x||_p = ||x||_\infty$ given $||x||_\infty = max(|x_1|,|x_2|)$

Tags: real-analysis

I have seen the proof done different ways, but none using the norm definitions provided.

Given:
$||x||_p = (|x_1|^p+|x_2|^p)^{1/p}$ and $||x||_\infty = max(|x_1|,|x_2|)$

Prove:
$\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}\|x\|_p = \|x\|_\infty$

I have looked at the similar questions:
[The $ l^{\infty} $-norm is equal to the limit of the $ l^{p} $-norms.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326172/the-l-infty-norm-is-equal-to-the-limit-of-the-lp-norms) and [Limit of $\|x\|_p$ as $p\rightarrow\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669051/limit-of-x-p-as-p-rightarrow-infty?lq=1) but they both seem to use quite different approaches (we have not covered homogeneity so that is out of the question, and the other uses a different definition for the infity norm).

Comment: Read the first question again, it is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Perhaps what is confusing you is that those questions are looking at the $p$-norm and $\infty$-norm on the space of sequences instead of on $\mathbb{R}^2$. It's not hard to ungeneralize the math done there.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: WLOG, assume $|x_1| \ge |x_2|$. Then, $\left(|x_1|^p+|x_2|^p\right)^{1/p} = |x_1|\left(1+\left(\dfrac{|x_2|}{|x_1|}\right)^p\right)^{1/p}$.

Can you show that this approaches $|x_1|$ as $p \to \infty$?